# R Xgboost validation error as stopping metric

Tags: r, xgboost

I am using a train and validation dataset on an xgboost binary classification model.

```
params5 <- list(booster = "gbtree", objective = "binary:logistic", 
            eta=0.0001, gamma=0.5, max_depth=15, min_child_weight=1, subsample=0.6,
            colsample_bytree=0.4,seed =2222)


xgb_MOD5 <- xgb.train (params = params5, data = dtrain, nrounds = 4000,
                   watchlist = list(validation = dvalid,train = dtrain), 
                   print_every_n =30,early_stopping_rounds = 100
                  maximize = F ,serialize = TRUE)
```

It automatically picks the train error as stopping metric. This results in the model continuing to train while overfitting.

```
Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use train_error for early stopping.
Will train until train_error hasn't improved in 100 rounds.
```

How do I assign the validation error as stopping metric?

Comment: try `xgb_MOD5 <- xgb.train (params = params5, data = dtrain, nrounds = 4000,
                   watchlist = list(validation = dvalid), 
                   print_every_n =30,early_stopping_rounds = 100
                  maximize = F ,serialize = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks,this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use the R binding of xgboost and the R-package documentation is not specific about it.  However, the [python-API documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) (see the `early_stopping_rounds` argument documentation) has a relevant clarification on this issue:

> Requires at least one item in `evals`. If there’s more than one, will use the last.

Here, `evals` is the list of samples on which metrics will be evaluated, i.e. it is analogous to your `watchlist` argument. So I would guess, it can be that you just need to swap the order of items in the list provided as that argument

Comment: Thank you. @abhiieor's  suggestion solved it. Since I had both dvalid and dtrain in the watchlist (i guess the equivalent of evals in python xgboost) it had chosen training error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @abhiieor for the solution. Adding to that from what I observed,when we use only the validation in watchlist:

```
xgb_MOD5 <- xgb.train (params = params5, data = dtrain, nrounds = 400,watchlist = list(validation = dvalid),
                   print_every_n =30,early_stopping_rounds = 100, maximize = F ,serialize = TRUE)
```

log results while it runs:

```
     [1]    validation-error:0.222037 
     Will train until validation_error hasn't improved in 100 rounds.

       [31] validation-error:0.201712 
       [61] validation-error:0.201635
```

And if we want to see both the train error and validation error while it runs,

*adding the validation as 2nd argument in the watch list  did it while using validation error as the stopping metric* .

```
xgb_MOD5 <- xgb.train (params = params5, data = dtrain, nrounds = 400,watchlist = list(train =dtrain,validation = dvalid),
                  print_every_n =30,early_stopping_rounds = 100, maximize = F ,serialize = TRUE)

       [1]  train-error:0.202131    validation-error:0.232341 
       Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use validation_error for early stopping.
      Will train until validation_error hasn't improved in 100 rounds.
       [31] train-error:0.174278    validation-error:0.202871 
       [61] train-error:0.173909    validation-error:0.202288
```